# height property does not show on Flutter BottomAppBarTheme

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, appbar

I am making a custom AppBar, with a bottom light grey line. When I add the `BottomAppBarTheme`, I can add only shape, elevation and color. But on Flutter [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomAppBarTheme-class.html), they also have `height`. Why I cannot add height on my AppBar?

**This is my main.dart:**

```
return GetMaterialApp(
  translations: GetXTranslations(), 
  locale: Locale('en', 'US'), 
  fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
  title: 'MyApp',
  theme: ThemeData(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme.of(context).copyWith(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  ),
    bottomAppBarTheme: BottomAppBarTheme.of(context).copyWith(
      color: ColorsConstants.grey100,
    ),
```

**Update:**
My bad. I was trying to add a bottom grey line to the AppBar, not to change is height. So maybe I was wrong, thinking to do it by customize the
`BottomAppBarTheme`.
Because I have a file looks like this one on the bottom, and I was trying to add this customization to my main.dart.

```
return Scaffold( backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('name'),
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(1.0),
        child: Container(
          color: ColorsConstants.grey100,
          height: 1.0,
        ),
      )
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: is your `Update` is answer? then consider including it on answer section

Comment: no my ```update``` it is not the answer, because I don't know how to add " bottom: PreferredSize() " to my main.dart

Answer (score 0):

in `bottomBarTheme` you can't add height for bottomBar. for `BottomAppBar` custom height you can try this

```
 bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
    height: 74,
    child: BottomAppBar(
      shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(), // Add your custom shape here
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: const <Widget>[
          ///.... // Your bottomBar tabs IconButtons
        ],
      ),
    ),
)
```

for appBar custom height use `toolbarHeight` property inside `AppBar` widget or in appBarTheme property too like this.

```
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme.of(context)
              .copyWith(backgroundColor: Colors.blue, toolbarHeight: 75)
```

Comment: yes you are right that in current stable version height property not showing but mentioned in doc but you can check this  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117537 i think it will resolve in upcoming flutter updates.

Comment: can you share what exact output you want ?

Comment: of course I can. The line you see under the Appbar is achieved with the bottom: PreferredSize()..